# How to use gensim with pytorch to create an intent classifier (With LSTM NN)?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, word2vec, torch

**The problem to solve:** Given a sentence, return the intent behind it (Think chatbot)

*Reduced example dataset (Intent on the left of dict):*

```
data_raw    = {"mk_reservation" : ["i want to make a reservation",
                                   "book a table for me"],
               "show_menu"      : ["what's the daily menu",
                                   "do you serve pizza"],
               "payment_method" : ["how can i pay",
                                   "can i use cash"],
               "schedule_info"  : ["when do you open",
                                   "at what time do you close"]}
```

I have stripped down the sentences with spaCy, and tokenized each word by using the **word2vec**  algorithm provided by the gensim library.

This is what resulted from the use of word2vec model GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin:

```
[[[ 5.99331968e-02  6.50703311e-02  5.03010787e-02 ... -8.00536275e-02
    1.94782894e-02 -1.83010306e-02]
  [-2.14406010e-02 -1.00447744e-01  6.13847338e-02 ... -6.72588721e-02
    3.03986594e-02 -4.14126664e-02]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]

 [[ 4.48647663e-02 -1.03907576e-02 -1.78682189e-02 ...  3.84555124e-02
   -2.29179319e-02 -2.05144612e-03]
  [-5.39291985e-02 -9.88398306e-03  4.39085700e-02 ... -3.55276838e-02
   -3.66208404e-02 -4.57760505e-03]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]]
```

- This is a List of sentences, and each sentence is a list of words (**[sentences[sentence[word]]]**)
- Each sentence (list) must be of size 10 words (I am padding the remaining with zeroes)
- Each word (list) has 300 elements (word2vec dimensions)

By following some tutorials i transformed this to a TensorDataset.

At this moment, i am very confused on how to use the word2vec and probably i have just been wasting time, as of now i believe the **embeddings layer** from an LSTM configuration should be composed by importing the word2vec model weights using:

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path/to/file')
weights = torch.FloatTensor(model.vectors)    
word_embeddings = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(weights)
```

This is not enough as pytorch is saying it does not accept embeddings where indices are not INT type  .

**EDIT: I found out that importing the weight matrix from gensim word2vec is not straightforward, one has to import the word_index table as well.**

As soon as i fix this issue i'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need neither a neural network nor word embeddings. Use parsed trees with NLTK, where intents are Verbs `V` acting on `entities` (N) in a given `utterance`:

[image: Phrase]

To classify a sentence, then you can use a Neural Net. I personally like BERT in fast.ai. Once again, you won't need embeddings to run the classification, and you can do it in multilanguage:

[Fast.ai_BERT_ULMFit](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2019/blob/master/Fast.ai_BERT_ULMFit/Fast.ai_BERT_ULMFit.ipynb)

Also, you can use `Named Entity Recognition` if you are working on a chatbot, to guide conversations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough training data, you may not need fancy neural networks (or even explicit word-vectorization). Just try basic text-classification algorithms (for example from `scikit-learn`) against basic text representations (such as a simple bag-of-words or bag-of-character n-grams).

If those don't work, or fail when confronted with novel words, then you might try fancier text vectorization options. For example, you might replace unknown words with the nearest-known-word from a large word2vec model. Or representing queries as averages-of-word-vectors – which is likely a better choice than creating giant concatenations of fixed length with zero-padding. Or use other algorithms for modeling the text, like 'Paragraph Vector' (`Doc2Vec` in `gensim`) or deeper neural-network modeling (which requires lots of data & training time).

(If you have or can acquire lots of domain-specific training data, training word-vectors on that text will likely give you more appropriate word-vectors than reusing those from `GoogleNews`. Those vectors were trained on professional news stories from a corpus circa 2013, which will have a very different set of word-spellings and prominent word-senses than what seems to be your main interest, user-typed queries.)